# OCaml union types

Tags: types, ocaml

I'm trying to make a function that uses a subtype of a defined type but OCaml wont derive the correct value :
Consider this type definition:

```
type fraction = {numerator : int; denominator : int};;

type number =
  | Int of int
  | Fraction of fraction;;
```

if i try to type into the interpeter (i'm using utop if it matters) :

```
utop # ((fun a-> a>0) (Int 1));;
Error: This expression has type number but an expression was expected of type int
```

type number is also an int but I cant get the function to understand that, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pattern matching in the `fun`:

```
# (fun (Int a) -> a > 0) (Int 1);;
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
Fraction _
- : bool = true
```

Obviously this will raise a match error if you pass in a `Fraction`. If you want to handle that case:

```
# (function Int a -> a > 0 | Fraction {numerator = a; denominator = b}  -> a/b > 0 ) (Int 1);;
- : bool = true
```

Answer (score 2):

The `0` in `a>0` is an `int`, so that is the type the function expects as an argument. What you probably want is for the `0` to be the equivalent `number`, like this:

```
# (fun a -> a > Int 0) (Int 1)
- : bool = true
```

Comment: No, I want to get to the integer inside, i need it later to create a fraction but its inside a 'number' type, I'm going to get a list of 'number' and I need to make it into a fraction, but I don't know how to get to the integer value inside

Comment: Then you'll want to pattern match on the `number`.